# iPad + HTML5 Video Tag + External display issue

Tags: ipad, video, html, ios

I am using HTML5 video tags in a UIWebview on the iPad, and positioning them as needed using CSS. The key part of these videos is that they are designed to take up part, but not all, of the visible area on the page. When I'm doing this in the "normal" mode of displaying content only to the primary UIScreen, everything works great.

However, when an external VGA projector is hooked up as a second UIScreen, the video tag content immediately becomes FULL SCREEN. This seems to also happen in Safari when looking at, for example, YouTube videos. In searching the docs, there seems to be no way to stop / control this behavior.

Is there any way to stop a video tag from forcing its content to go to full screen when a second display is connected?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, using a UIWebView iOS 3.2 doesn't offer any way to do this. Video in a UIWebView always plays fullscreen on an external display using the TV out feature.

However, the good news is that iOS 4 does offer a solution. UIWebView has a couple of new properties:

allowsInlineMediaPlayback
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW32

mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW33

The former will allow the videos to remain 'inline' as opposed to using the full-screen player.

Comment: This does not work for me. I've tested it with an iPad 1 with iOS 4.3 and an external display connected via HDMI using the Digital AV Adapter. 
Even if I set allowsInlineMediaPlayback and mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction to YES, videos still play fullscreen on the external display and the UIWebView shows a message like "TV Connected - This video is playing on the TV".
Could you please provide more pointers with which setup this worked for you? Thanks.

Comment: The iOS 4 solution came from Apple support. It may very well be that the specifics have changed between 4.0 and 4.3. I will do some research and get back to you...

Comment: Did you test it on a 4.0 device? It would be interesting to know if something changed between 4.0 and 4.3.